# How can I estimate the dark matter density for some specific galaxies by using the rotation curves?

Tags: astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

I have rotation curve data (radius vs rotational velocity) for some specific galaxies. How can I estimate the dark matter density for those specific galaxies by using the rotation curves? Or is there such a method to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, can you clarify whether you want to estimate the dark matter profile (as a function of $r$) or whether you are just interested in the total amount of dark matter within some radius.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of model (the dependence of density on $r$) for how the dark matter behaves (e.g., a [Navarro, Frenk & White profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navarro%E2%80%93Frenk%E2%80%93White_profile)) with some free parameters like a scale radius and central density and then some observational constraints on the normal matter density profile, perhaps from how much light it emits. The sum of these two will be the total gravitating matter density.

From there you need to solve the equations of motion using the gravitational forces exerted on something at radius $r$ to predict what the circular orbital speed would be at radius $r$. This model, along with the observational rotation curves are then put into something like a Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) Bayesian estimator to give you the posterior probability distribution for the free parameters in your dark matter model.

This is just a general description - the specifics would depend on the specifics of the data you have.

A simpler method (which however does use a major approximation):

Again, you need to have some idea of how much normal matter there is within some radius $r$.
From there, *assume spherical symmetry*, so that you can say
$$ \frac{G M(<r)}{r^2} = \frac{v(r)^2}{r}$$.
From each discrete value you have of $v(r)$ you can get an estimate of $M(<r)$, the mass inside radius $r$. If you subtract off your estimate for how much normal matter there is within that radius you get an estimate of how much dark matter there is within $r$. Differentiating $M_{\rm dark}(<r)$ with respect to $r$ and dividing by $4\pi r^2$ gives you an approximation for the dark matter density profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can find density profile from the velocity profile by recognizing that the rotational velocity profile can be determined from the gravitational potential,
$$\frac{mv^2}{2}=m\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}r}.\tag{1}$$
And from the gravitational potential, you can find the density via the Poisson equation,
$$\nabla^2\Phi(r)=-4\pi G\rho(r).\tag{2}$$
So it's a matter of finding a potential $\Phi$ that matches Eq (1) and then differentiating it twice to get the density in Eq (2).

I imagine that you have discrete data, so would have to determine a functional form of $v(r)$ using [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting), then proceed with the above.

Comment: Now that I see ProfRobs answer, it seems I totally forgot that $\Phi(r)=\Phi_\text{matter}(r)+\Phi_\text{halo}(r)$. It probably would be better to perform the opposite analysis as my suggestion (i.e., estimate an $\rho(r)$ for both matter & dark matter components and try matching it to $v(r)$).